# CORS error connecting React/Typescript frontend to Flask/Python/PostgreSQL backend

Tags: reactjs, python-3.x, typescript, flask-cors

I am unable to connect my frontend(local 3000) to my backend (local 8000) because of this error in the console of developer tools in my chrome browser:
[image: CORS error]

When I cURL the specific route, I see that Access-Control-Allow-Origin is "*".
[image]

Please help! I don't know where to go from here and it seems like a simple issue.

My relevant frontend code:
**src/api/api.ts**:

```
import axios from "axios";

// fetch quotes
export const getAuthors = async () => {

    const URL = "http://localhost:8000/api/v1"

    try {
        const response = await axios.get(`${URL}/authors`)
        console.log(response.data)
        return response.data
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching quotes:', error)
        throw error
    }
}
```

**src/pages/Quotes.tsx**:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState} from "react";
import { getAuthors } from '../api/api'


const Quotes = () => {
    const [authors, setAuthors] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchAuthors()
    }, [])

    const fetchAuthors = async () => {
        try {
            const response = await getAuthors()
            console.log('API Response:', response)
            setAuthors(response.data)
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error fetching quotes:', error)
            
        }
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Quotes</h1>
            <ul>
                {authors.map((author: any) => (
                    <li key={author.id}>
                        <strong>{author.name}</strong>
                        <ul>
                        {Array.isArray(author.quote) && author.quote.map((quote: { id: string, quote: string, source: string }) => (
                            <li key={quote.id}>
                            {quote.quote} - <em>{quote.source}</em>
                            </li>
                        ))}
            </ul>

                    </li>

                ))}
            </ul>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Quotes
```

**src/pages/App.tsx**:

```
import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import Quotes from './pages/Quotes';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

function App() {

  

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/quotes" element={<Quotes />} />
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Relevant backend code:
**app.py**:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify
from flask_cors import CORS
import models
from flask_login import LoginManager
from resources.authors import authors
from resources.categories import categories

DEBUG = True
PORT = 8000

login_manager = LoginManager()

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'VENIVEDIVICI'

login_manager.init_app(app)

# CORS arguments go here
CORS(app)


# Register blueprints with the app
app.register_blueprint(authors, url_prefix='/api/v1/authors')
app.register_blueprint(categories, url_prefix='/api/v1/categories')




if __name__ == '__main__':
    models.initialize()
    app.run(debug=DEBUG, port=PORT)
```

**resources/authors.py**:

```
from models import Author
from flask import Blueprint, jsonify, Flask
from playhouse.shortcuts import model_to_dict


# Blueprint
authors = Blueprint('authors', __name__)

# Route for all authors
@authors.route('/', methods=["GET"])
def get_authors():
    # Get all authors
    authors_query = Author.select()
    print(authors_query)

    # Convert author data to dictionary
    author_dict = [model_to_dict(author)for author in authors_query]
    
    # Return JSON data
    return jsonify({
        'data': author_dict,
        'message': f"Successfully found {len(author_dict)} authors",
        'status': 200
        }), 200
```

I have tried everything: **CORS(app)**, **CORS(app, origins="http://localhost:3000", methods=["GET"]**, **added @cross_origin to the route I am trying to hit, all of these have given the same error above**. Yes, flask-cors is installed on the backend.